# Using \typeC in package skak will not compile

Tags: skak

(1) I am using MikTeX 2.9 and am generally a very happy user of `skak` - barely two hours seperated the moment I wanted to typeset a chess problem and knowing absolutely nothing about what support there might be in LaTeX and having `skak` up and running and producing. However, I have just hit a hurdle: any attempt to invoke `\styleC` (which prints moves as a vertical array of 2 half moves per line) results in compilation errors, while `\styleA` and `\styleB` produce the intended results. What puzzles me even more is the fact that I have no problem compiling the `skakdoc.tex` file supplied in the distribution and I am using exactly the same list of `\usepackage` instructions in my document as `skakdoc` does. What the heck?

(2) While on the subject of styles, wouldn't it be nice to have a style that will represent chess pieces with their letters (e.g. R for rook, N for knight etc.) in place of showing their symbols. I find that invoking `skak` with the 'small' parameter makes reading text somewhat marginal, particularly the bishops are hard to spot. I find modern chess literature supports both styles so I imagine such a letter-style would not go astray with users of `skak`.

---

Apologies for starting a goose chase with this one. My original code used the \mainline{} instruction followed by a linefeed, which is OK for styles A and B. When switching to \styleC this linefeed caused a compiler error; unfortunately my error messages after compilation have never worked properly, so I never got the explicit message "no line to end here".

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
\newgame
\styleA
\textbf{styleA}\\
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d3} \\
\\
\newgame
\styleB
\textbf{styleB}\\
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d3} \\
\\
Note: while linefeeds may follow the mainline command for style A and B, a linefeed following the mainline command when styleC is set causes compiler error "there is no line to end here".\\
\newgame
\styleC
\textbf{styleC}\\
\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Bc5 4.c3 Nf6 5.d3}%\\ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question. `skak` uses internally the `chessfss` package which offers an option to switch to letters:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\newgame
\usetextfig
\settextfiglanguage{german}

\mainline{1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Rg1 Rg8}

\end{document}
```

(I would naturally use `xskak` instead of `skak`).

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, that worked. And what is the switch back to using symbols?

Comment: `\usesymfig`. See 4.4 Commands that can switch between text and symbols of the chessfss documentation.

Comment: ... and thanks again, that's what I call prompt service! On the subject of \styleC: still will not compile if used in my document, and yet, it will correctly compile in the skakdoc.tex document which I pulled off the archive. The workaround is using individual \mainline instructions separted by linefeeds \\, which of course is becoming a nuisance.

Comment: As egreg has already told you: make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ... I will as soon as I have recovered the skill of putting code into my submission.

Comment: \styleC works, see the answer to my own question. I do notice that move lines are printed wide, and they adjust if multiplecols are used. Is there a way to set the width via a parameter? I browsed through the xskak document but could not find a reference to display width.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: The default definition use `\linewidth`. But you can define your own style "styleD". Search in `xskak.sty` for styleC (3 hits in 2 items), copy the code to your preamble and change to your liking.

Comment: What I find in my MiKTeX2.9 distribution is:

Comment: I am not getting anywhere with my reply to your \styleD suggestion above, don't know how to add code etc. in the Comment format. So I will make this a new question.